# Checkout and commit a repository from another repository

Tags: git, msbuild, repository, msbuild-task

I am using MsBuild to build an application ProjectA, we are using Git, I start to pull the code from Git of ProjectA, then I need to commit some DLLs from ProjectA to ProjectB repository

This is what I am trying to do:

```
   <Exec Command="git reset --hard"/>
       <Exec Command="git clean -fxd"/>
       <Exec Command="git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main"/>
```

But the `git reset --hard` command and the `git clean` and the `git branch` are done in the repository of ProjectA.

Even if I did the `cd`.

When I tried in the git bash the commands are working correctly

Comment: project A and project B are different repositories and can be cloned in ANY directory by ANYONE. How will you make sure that whoever is executing the task has cloned it properly in proper location?

Answer (score 0):

If each `<Exec .../>` instruction is ran in a separate shell (e.g: something like `cmd.exe /c "cd foo\bar"`), the "change working directory" part will be lost when `cmd.exe` returns.
`cd` only acts on the working directory of the current process, it does not "stay" on the calling process.

---

A generic fix is to turn your commands to `cd foo\bar && something else ...`,
when using `git` commands, you can actually set the repo to work on through a command line argument :

```
git -C foo\bar reset --hard
git -C foo\bar clean -fxd
git -C foo\bar branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main
# etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the way you are doing it is a good idea to pass dlls between repositories, but here is the way to pass working directory to `Exec` so that your command works on that directory:

```
<Exec Command="git reset --hard" WorkingDirectory="Path to project B" />
```